# Probability of two dice against one

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, conditional-probability

If you roll two dice, what are the odds that at least one has a higher value than a third die you roll?" And for (B), it's the same as (A) except you roll three dice before checking against a fourth?

Comment: OK, what did you try?

Comment: Hint:  just work cases.  Suppose the third is a $1$, what is the probability that neither of the first two (or three) were higher?  Now suppose the third is a $2$...and so on.

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like routine homework problems and which show no effort.  What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I tried to do the sum of the single probability. For 2 dice 15/36 + 15/36 -15/36 * 15/36 but it doesnt work

Comment: @lulu thanks for the advice. I just posted what I tried. What do you think?

Comment: I don't understand your calculation.  Look at my first comment...it gives a road map for solving the problem.

Comment: @lulu for 2 dice: If I roll 2 dice there are 36 output combination. 15 of them are those that I want to count ( Die1<Die2). At this point I can do the same thing with another die D3. So, P(D2 U D3) = P(D2) + P(D3) -P(D2*D3).

But its not right unfortunately

Comment: Why do you care whether $die_1$ is greater than $die_2$?  You just need $die_3$ to be $≥$ both of them.

Comment: @lulu so do you think that the probability is just that one of D3? 15/36 I guess... No its not, even because if you roll 300 dice with this reasoning the probability is still 15/36

Comment: I didn't say anything like that.  Please try to follow the hint suggested in my first comment.

Comment: Worth noting:  the program I suggest in the hint is intended to compute the complementary probability, that is...it computes the probability that neither of the first two (or three) dice show a greater value than the last one.  For problems like this, it is often easier to work with the complement.

Comment: Note too:  your idea of checking the case when you roll a large number of dice initially is a good one.  It's easy to see that the answer in that case has to approach $\frac 56$:  for large $n$ it is effectively certain that you'll get at least one $6$ out of the first $n$ rolls, so the only way to win is for the final die to be a $6$. You should be able to check that whatever method you end up using agrees with this in the limit.

Comment: So, indipendence rolling: P(D1*D2) = 21/36 * 21/36 (both less than the first) 
doesnt work....@lulu

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Knowing that $d_1<d_3$ is evidence that $d_3$ is large, so the events you are looking at are clearly not independent.  Not sure why you are reluctant to try to follow the program I sketched out in my hint.  Anyway, I have posted that computation below.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3000997/probably-of-winning-with-2-dice-maximum-of-them-against-another-one) question.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s try asking “If I were to roll a number $k$ before rolling a $6$-sided dice, then what would be the chance the second die would have a lowet value than the other?”

Let us try $k=1$. We can roll the numbers $2,3,4,5,6$ to top that $1$. Since there are $6$ possibilities, and only $1$ does not meat the requirement, the probability of getting equal or less is $\frac16$. For $k=2$ there are $2$ possibilities=$\frac26$, for $k=3$ there are $3$ possibilities=$\frac36$ e.t.c.

Now what if we were to use $2$ dice? The second die has the same probability as the first as they are identical, so we square the chance for $1$ die of being under or equal to $1$ and the answer would be $\left(\frac16\right)^2=\frac1{36}$ for $k=1$.

But we’re not finding the probability of the dice being under or equal to $k$, are we? Thankfully the probability of getting over $k$ for $2$ dice would be $1-\frac1{36}=\frac{6^2-1^2}{6^2}$.

Finally, let’s factor in the various values of $k$. Remember, the deominater will not be $6^2$ but $6^3$ because that is the number of possibilities for $3$ dice (first and second dice, and the value of $k$) so the answer will be $$\frac{6^2-1^2+6^2-2^2+6^2-3^2+6^2-4^2+6^2-5^2+6^2-6^2}{6^3}$$, which is $\frac{125}{216}$

For the second answer, change the exponents by one to get $$\frac{6^3-1^3+6^3-2^3+6^3-3^3+6^3-4^3+6^3-5^3+6^3-6^3}{6^4}$$

Comment: this response pretend to know one of the result. We dont know what the first roller ll obtain...

Comment: Well, we know that they all have an equal chance of happening, so we can take the average of them all. Think of it like this: In a probability tree, we can assume that a branch has probability $1$ of happening even if it has, say, $\frac13$ chance of happening. After we calculate the chance of a sub-branch happening, we just multiply by $\frac13$ to calculate the overall chance of happening. We know that the chance of $k=1$ is $\frac16$ because there are $6$ equal possibilities of $k$, but I’ve only considered it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ denote the number of dice thrown prior to the last one (so you are asked about $n=2,3$).

it is easier to work with the complementary event...the probability that none of the first $n$ dice exceed the last one.

Suppose the final die shows $i$ (probability $\frac 16$ of course). Of course, the probability that a given die shows $≤i$ is $\frac i6$.  Thus the probability that all $n$ of the prior dice show $≤i$ is $\left(\frac i6\right)^n$.  It follows that the probability none of the first $n$ die exceed the final one is $$q_n=\frac 16\times \sum_{i=1}^6 \left(\frac i6\right)^n$$

It is easy to compute $$q_2=\frac {91}{216}\quad \& \quad q_3=\frac {49}{144}$$

So the answer you want, $p_n=1-q_n$ is given by $$p_2=\frac {125}{216}\quad \&\quad p_3=\frac {95}{144}$$

Sanity check:  Note that, for large $n$, it is effectively certain that we'll get at least one $6$ in the initial $n$ tosses, so we expect $p_n\to \frac 56$ as $n$ gets large.  Using a machine, it is easy to verify that $q_n\to \frac 16$ as $n$ gets large, as expected. Or, algebraically, it is clear that $\left(\frac i6\right)^n\to 0$ for $i<6$ so the only term in the sum that survives has $i=6$ which makes the limit apparent.

Comment: It follows that the probability none of the first n die exceed the final one is qn..... Why 1/6 and sum? I was going to say that it was just (i/6)^n

Comment: We are working case by case, according to the value shown by the final die.  The probability that the final die shows $i$ is $\frac 16$.

Comment: I m really trying to understand but I dont... Could you please explaine one more time how did you write qn? For example with 2 dice vs one

Comment: Please spend some more time on it.  Fix $n=2$.  Now look at the first case, $i=1$.  We are in that case with probability $\frac 16$.  Analyze that completely.  Now do the second case, $i=2$.  We are in that case with probability $\frac 16$.  Analyze that case completely.  Now do $i=3$ and so on.

Comment: As another suggestion, use my method to handle the case $n=1$.  Of course, you already know that that the answer in that case is $p_1=\frac {15}{36}=\frac 5{12}$ (so $q_1=\frac 7{12}$). See if you can use my method to get that result.